# What is the fastest and generic way to flatten deeply nested JSON to get a Dataframe?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do some descriptives on my own location data that I got from my Google timeline. But when trying to get some workable data, to convert it from a JSON-file to a DataFrame. It brought up some questions that I would like to have some answers to because when trying to convert the JSON-file to a DataFrame it felt for me that I was going to do it in an inefficient way.

To give a description of what my JSON looks like. It is a JSON of 3 levels deep and has around 4.5 million lines. A small example of the JSON:

```
"locations" : [ 
{
  "timestampMs" : "1489591483",
  "latitudeE7" : -21.61909,
  "longitudeE7" : 121.65283,
  "accuracy" : 23,
  "velocity" : 18,
  "heading" : 182,
  "altitude" : 55,
  "activity" : [ {
    "timestampMs" : "1489591507",
    "activity" : [ {
      "type" : "IN_VEHICLE",
      "confidence" : 49
    }, {
      "type" : "UNKNOWN",
      "confidence" : 17
    }, {
      "type" : "ON_BICYCLE",
      "confidence" : 15
    }, {
      "type" : "ON_FOOT",
      "confidence" : 9
    }, {
      "type" : "STILL",
      "confidence" : 9
    }, {
      "type" : "WALKING",
      "confidence" : 9
    } ]
  } ]
},
...
]
```

To convert it to a DataFrame I want to flatten those 3 levels down to 0 levels. I have seen some implementations with json_normalize in combination with .apply or .append but therefore you still needed to know the key to the value, which I would have rather seen to be more generic (so without knowing the key). And it also required to manually iterate over the values. Now what I would like to know is: "Is there a method that automatically flattens the JSON down to 0 levels without using apply or append?" If there isn't such a method, what would be the preferred way of flatting JSON and converting it to a DataFrame?

---

Edit: Added an example of what the DataFrame should look like and a better example of the JSON.

---

To give a small example of what the DataFrame should look like, see the image below:
[image: An example of DataFrame]

To include a better example of what the JSON looks like I have included a Pastebin URL below:
[tiny location history sample](https://pastebin.com/K53pNQPH)

Comment: Could you give a small example of what you want the dataframe to look like given the JSON snippet you have?

Comment: Also, would help if you give a valid json.  just take your full data and pare it down to a smaller version with the same general format.

Comment: @BradSolomon I added an example of how the DataFrame should look based on the JSON and I have added an URL to Pastebin with a larger JSON example. The longitude, latitude and timestamps are random numbers inside the Pastebin example. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Use `json_normalize`, specifying the `record_path` and `meta_path`.

```
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(d, ['locations', 'activity', 'activity'], 
                         ['locations', ['locations', 'activity', 'timestampMs']])
df = df.drop('locations', 1).add_prefix('activity.')
v = pd.DataFrame(df['locations'].tolist()).drop('activity', 1)    

pd.concat([df, v], 1)


   activity.confidence activity.type activity.locations.activity.timestampMs  \
0                   49    IN_VEHICLE                              1489591507   
1                   17       UNKNOWN                              1489591507   
2                   15    ON_BICYCLE                              1489591507   
3                    9       ON_FOOT                              1489591507   
4                    9         STILL                              1489591507   
5                    9       WALKING                              1489591507   

   accuracy  altitude  heading  latitudeE7  longitudeE7 timestampMs  velocity  
0        23        55      182   -21.61909    121.65283  1489591483        18  
1        23        55      182   -21.61909    121.65283  1489591483        18  
2        23        55      182   -21.61909    121.65283  1489591483        18  
3        23        55      182   -21.61909    121.65283  1489591483        18  
4        23        55      182   -21.61909    121.65283  1489591483        18  
5        23        55      182   -21.61909    121.65283  1489591483        18
```

Comment: So it is always required to pass the keys to the values and it cannot be done generically? In which json_normalize would find out himself how to flatten the JSON?

Comment: @user3473161 json_normalize can’t work wonders. You still need to tell it how to process the data. In some instances the structure is trivial enough that it infers things itself. But in cases like this, you need to give it a hand. This is also partly a consequence of how poorly documented the API is, and there might be another way to do it, but god knows I don’t know what it is.

Comment: I did not expect any different, but I can always hope. I am quite spoiled with the luxury that some frameworks have to offer. Quite often that includes a nice method in which you do not have to specify anything at all and it knows how to solve the issue. But indeed as you mentioned; it isn't standing in the documentation but that does not always mean it isn't there, it might not have been documented yet. And because I am just learning Pandas and I would like to yearn it in a perfect way I asked this question. Just to be sure that I am not missing something that is there.

Comment: I changed my question a bit, because of your comment I realized that I need to emphasise the generic part.

Comment: @user3473161 Your question is a bit old. Why not open a new question saying "this the code I'm using ... can it be made more generic?"

Comment: I do not know if I am going to, it feels like I would be spamming StackOverflow too much with a partly duplicate question because it looks a lot like this one. I do not know if that would be in compliance with the rules/guidelines of StackOverflow.

Comment: @user3473161 Follow up questions are okay, and pandas is very forgiving as a tag.

Comment: @user3473161 pls see my answer below.. if that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You need.. `flatten_json` library: https://github.com/amirziai/flatten

then use this function and code to automagically convert deeply nested json to pandas dataframe

```
from flatten_json import flatten
#testjson sample string is provided further below

def jsonNormalize(data):
    dic_flattened = (flatten(dd) for dd in data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(dic_flattened)
    return df


# flatten(testjson)
df1 = jsonNormalize(testjson)
df1
```

This will generate dataframe df like this:
[image: 1]

testjson sample string as below:

```
testjson = [{"locations" : [ 
{
  "timestampMs" : "1489591483",
  "latitudeE7" : -21.61909,
  "longitudeE7" : 121.65283,
  "accuracy" : 23,
  "velocity" : 18,
  "heading" : 182,
  "altitude" : 55,
  "activity" : [ {
    "timestampMs" : "1489591507",
    "activity" : [ {
      "type" : "IN_VEHICLE",
      "confidence" : 49
    }, {
      "type" : "UNKNOWN",
      "confidence" : 17
    }, {
      "type" : "ON_BICYCLE",
      "confidence" : 15
    }, {
      "type" : "ON_FOOT",
      "confidence" : 9
    }, {
      "type" : "STILL",
      "confidence" : 9
    }, {
      "type" : "WALKING",
      "confidence" : 9
    } ]
  } ]
}
]},
           {"locations" : [ 
{
  "timestampMs" : "1489591483",
  "latitudeE7" : -21.61909,
  "longitudeE7" : 121.65283,
  "accuracy" : 23,
  "velocity" : 18,
  "heading" : 182,
  "altitude" : 55,
  "activity" : [ {
    "timestampMs" : "1489591507",
    "activity" : [ {
      "type" : "IN_VEHICLE",
      "confidence" : 49
    }, {
      "type" : "UNKNOWN",
      "confidence" : 17
    }, {
      "type" : "ON_BICYCLE",
      "confidence" : 15
    }, {
      "type" : "ON_FOOT",
      "confidence" : 9
    }, {
      "type" : "STILL",
      "confidence" : 9
    }, {
      "type" : "WALKING",
      "confidence" : 9
    } ]
  } ]
}
]}]
```