# Flattening list of dicts columns from a converted Json file to Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested, flatten

I'm trying to convert a Json file to a Dataframe using Pandas and json_normalize. The json file is like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1Y3o.png)

Then my Dataframe is like this after reading the file and using json_normalize

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Md2pU.png)

but some columns are not flattened and they are list of dicts. I used many methods that was talked about it here but non of them works. I even used a function that was also from one of the questions here,

```py
def flatten_nested_json_df(df):

    df = df.reset_index()

    print(f"original shape: {df.shape}")
    print(f"original columns: {df.columns}")


    # search for columns to explode/flatten
    s = (df.applymap(type) == list).all()
    list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

    s = (df.applymap(type) == dict).all()
    dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

    print(f"lists: {list_columns}, dicts: {dict_columns}")
    while len(list_columns) > 0 or len(dict_columns) > 0:
        new_columns = []

        for col in dict_columns:
            print(f"flattening: {col}")
            # explode dictionaries horizontally, adding new columns
            horiz_exploded = pd.json_normalize(df[col]).add_prefix(f'{col}.')
            horiz_exploded.index = df.index
            df = pd.concat([df, horiz_exploded], axis=1).drop(columns=[col])
            new_columns.extend(horiz_exploded.columns) # inplace

        for col in list_columns:
            print(f"exploding: {col}")
            # explode lists vertically, adding new columns
            df = df.drop(columns=[col]).join(df[col].explode().to_frame())
            new_columns.append(col)

        # check if there are still dict o list fields to flatten
        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == list).all()
        list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == dict).all()
        dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

        print(f"lists: {list_columns}, dicts: {dict_columns}")

    print(f"final shape: {df.shape}")
    print(f"final columns: {df.columns}")
    return df
```

but it didn't flatten my columns and instead of changing the numbers of of my columns, the number of my rows increased. I hope you can help me with this issue. Thanks!

Comment: deep flatten your nested json before passing to json_normalise

Comment: Please paste the JSON file as taxt, not screenshot

Comment: @parveshKumar Thanks, How should I do the deep flatten?

Comment: Tried answers for flattening here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47367665/what-is-the-fastest-and-generic-way-to-flatten-deeply-nested-json-to-get-a-dataf?